# Pattern is being printed weird when used in an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have created an array and some functions that print different patterns each. My problem is that they are printed inside the array in a weird way. The below is the main part of the code and just one function for the example.

```
int castle(int patternWidth, int doorStart, int doorEnd, int N, int i, int j, int row, int col, char** array) 
    {
        if (N >= 3 && N <= 20) 
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= (N + 1); i++) 
            {
                array[row][col] = '*'; col++;
                array[row][col] = ' '; col++;
            }
            row++;

            patternWidth = (((N + 1) * 2) - 1);
            doorStart = (patternWidth - 3) / 2; 
            doorEnd = doorStart + 3; 


            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            { 
                for (j = 1; j <= patternWidth; j++) 
                { 
                    if(N - i <= 2 && j > doorStart && j <= doorEnd)
                    {
                        array[row][col] = ' '; col++;
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        array[row][col] = '*'; col++;
                    }
                }
                row++;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int main() 
        {
            int N = 0, M = 0, i = 0, j = 0, a = 0, b = 0, s = 0, width = 0, height = 0, patternWidth = 0, doorStart = 0, doorEnd = 0, option = 0, num = 3, col = 0, row = 0;
            char** array;

            printf("Give height board size:");
            scanf("%d", &height);
            printf("Give width board size:");
            scanf("%d", &width);

            array = (char**)malloc(height * sizeof(char*));
            for (i = 0; i < width; i++) 
            {
                array[i] = (char*)malloc(height * sizeof(char));
            }


            for (i = 0; i < height; i++) 
            {
                for (j = 0; j < width; j++) 
                {
                    array[i][j] = ' ';
                }
            }

            while (option != 6)
            {
                printf("\nOption: 1-5, 6 to exit\n"
                "1) Stairs and flag\n"
                "2) Castle\n"
                "3) Trap door\n"
                "4) Platform\n"
                "5) Obstacles\n"
                "Option:");
                scanf("%d", &option);
                if (option == 1) 
                {
                    printf("Valid values 6 - 20\n");
                    printf("Size:");
                    scanf("%d", &N);
                    printf("Height Position:");
                    scanf("%d", &row);
                    printf("Width Position:");
                    scanf("%d", &col);
                    stairs_flag(N, i, j, b, a, num, col, row, array);
                }
                else if (option == 2) 
                {
                    printf("Valid values 3 - 15\n");
                    printf("Size:");
                    scanf("%d", &N);
                    printf("Height Position:");
                    scanf("%d", &row);
                    printf("Width Position:");
                    scanf("%d", &col);
                    castle(patternWidth, doorStart, doorEnd, N, i, j, row, col, array);
                }
                else if (option == 3) 
                {
                    printf("Valid values 3 - 18\n");
                    printf("Size of N:");
                    scanf("%d", &N);
                    printf("Height Position:");
                    scanf("%d", &row);
                    printf("Width Position:");
                    scanf("%d", &col);
                    trap_door(N, patternWidth, i, j, col, row, array);
                }
                else if (option == 4) 
                {
                    printf("Valid values of N 3 - 20\n");
                    printf("Size of N:");
                    scanf("%d", &N);
                    printf("Valid values of M 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20\n");
                    printf("Size of M");
                    scanf("%d", &M);
                    printf("Height Position:");
                    scanf("%d", &row);
                    printf("Width Position:");
                    scanf("%d", &col);
                    platform(N, M, i, j, col, row, array);
                }
                else if (option == 5) 
                {
                    printf("Valid values 2 - 10\n");
                    printf("Size of N:");
                    scanf("%d", &N);
                    printf("Height Position:");
                    scanf("%d", &row);
                    printf("Width Position:");
                    scanf("%d", &col);
                    obstacles(N, i, s, j, patternWidth, row, col, array);
                }

            print_array(array, height, width);
            }       

            free(array);

            return 0;
        }
```

The expected result and the correct one is this :

```
 |------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |          * * * * *                                         |
 |          *********                                         |
 |          *********                                         |
 |          ***   ***                                         |
 |          ***   ***                                         |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |------------------------------------------------------------|
```

But the actual result is this:

```
 |------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |          * * * * *                                         |
 |                    *********                               |
 |                             *********                      |
 |                                      ***   ***             |
 |                                               ***   ***    |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |                                                            |
 |------------------------------------------------------------|
```

For example, in the two arrays above, the board is 60 width and 20 height and for the pattern I gave the position 10 for both height and width. Every line of the pattern should be under the previous one and print a pattern but in reality it prints every line under the previous one but further more than the previous. How can I correct this? Is there any mistake in the function code. For every function I have done the same thing. I've put `array[row][col] = '*'; col++;` for the asterisks and `array[row][col] = ' '; col++;` for the spaces and `row++;` to print each line in a new line.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your column index `col` keeps increasing throughout the `castle()` function. If you want the asterisks to be aligned under each other, you need to set the column index back to its original value at the start of the for-loops.

For example, you could make it

```
int castle(int patternWidth, int doorStart, int doorEnd, int N, int i, int j, int row, int col, char** array) 
    { 
        int column_index = col;
        if (N >= 3 && N <= 20) 
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= (N + 1); i++) 
            {
                array[row][col] = '*'; col++;
                array[row][col] = ' '; col++;
            }
            row++;

            patternWidth = (((N + 1) * 2) - 1);
            doorStart = (patternWidth - 3) / 2; 
            doorEnd = doorStart + 3; 


            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            { 
                for (j = 1; j <= patternWidth; j++) 
                { 
                    col = column_index;
                    if(N - i <= 2 && j > doorStart && j <= doorEnd)
                    {
                        array[row][col] = ' '; col++;
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        array[row][col] = '*'; col++;
                    }
                }
                row++;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

where I added a command `int column_index = col;` which stores the original value at the start of the function, and a line `col = column_index;` at the start of the inner for-loop, putting the stored value back in the variable.